# Получение ключей Memcached с удаленного сервера

Tags: php, centos, memcached, zend-framework-2

Добрый день, коллеги!

На проекте с 2 распределенными машинами, условно api1 и api2, настроил кэширование Memcached. Машина api2 записывает ключи Memcached, машина api1 по этому ключу должна получить значение переменной с сервера api1. Проблема в том, что ключи генерируются простейшим образом:

```
public function createGUID() {
    return md5(uniqid(rand(),1));
}
```

При этом на машине api1 я не могу получить часть сохраненных ключей.

На машине api2 сохраняю ключи в Memcached:

```
public function testAction() {

    $cacheConfig = new \Zend\Config\Config(include('config/autoload/cache.local.php'));

    $content = new \stdClass();
    $content->content = 'Something content';


    $cache = \Zend\Cache\StorageFactory::factory($cacheConfig['caches'][$cacheConfig['caches']['usedStorage']]);

    $cache->setItem('taskA9E3254AEE074BF7AD7EAF7B9B376589', $content);
    $cache->setItem('requestFC20B3AFAC5C4376998086BB3983A260', $content);

echo "<br> 1. ";
    $requestData = $cache->getItem('taskA9E3254AEE074BF7AD7EAF7B9B376589');
    var_dump($requestData );

echo "<br> 2. ";        
    $requestData = $cache->getItem('requestFC20B3AFAC5C4376998086BB3983A260');
    var_dump($requestData );

    $cache->setItem('taskD9876B90BFCF4A3D9632205F77DCBB76', $content);
    $cache->setItem('request72D43014B6864BA98C217468C390B84A', $content);

echo "<br> 3. ";
    $requestData = $cache->getItem('taskD9876B90BFCF4A3D9632205F77DCBB76');
    var_dump($requestData );

echo "<br> 4. ";        
    $requestData = $cache->getItem('request72D43014B6864BA98C217468C390B84A');
    var_dump($requestData );


    die;
}
```

Результат:

```
1. object(stdClass)#331 (1) { ["content"]=> string(17) "Something content" } 
2. object(stdClass)#332 (1) { ["content"]=> string(17) "Something content" } 
3. object(stdClass)#336 (1) { ["content"]=> string(17) "Something content" } 
4. object(stdClass)#339 (1) { ["content"]=> string(17) "Something content" }
```

На машине api1 пытаюсь получить переменные по этим ключам:

```
public function testAction() {

    $cacheConfig = new \Zend\Config\Config(include('config/autoload/cache.local.php'));

    $content = new \stdClass();
    $content->content = 'Something content';


    $cache = \Zend\Cache\StorageFactory::factory($cacheConfig['caches'][$cacheConfig['caches']['usedStorage']]);

echo "<br> 1. ";
    $requestData = $cache->getItem('taskA9E3254AEE074BF7AD7EAF7B9B376589');
    var_dump($requestData );

echo "<br> 2. ";        
    $requestData = $cache->getItem('requestFC20B3AFAC5C4376998086BB3983A260');
    var_dump($requestData );

echo "<br> 3. ";
    $requestData = $cache->getItem('taskD9876B90BFCF4A3D9632205F77DCBB76');
    var_dump($requestData );

echo "<br> 4. ";        
    $requestData = $cache->getItem('request72D43014B6864BA98C217468C390B84A');
    var_dump($requestData );


    die;
}
```

Результат:

```
1. object(stdClass)#335 (1) { ["content"]=> string(17) "Something content" } 
2. object(stdClass)#331 (1) { ["content"]=> string(17) "Something content" } 
3. NULL 
4. NULL
```

Как видно на примере, примеры 1 и 2 я могу получить с удаленной машины, а примеры 3 и 4 не могу.

Прошу высказывать любые идеи!

upd: Чистый не зендовый Memcached такой ключ с удаленного сервера получает нормально.

```
    $m = new \Memcached();
    $m->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);
    $m->addServer('*.*.*.*', 11211);
    $m->addServer('*.*.*.*', 11211);

    echo "<br> 5. ";
    var_dump($m->get('taskD9876B90BFCF4A3D9632205F77DCBB76'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в непонимании работы MemCached с пулом серверов.

Если в ZF2 указываешь пул серверов для MemCached, то ключ будет получаться с одного случайного сервера из этого пула. Если на случайно выбранном сервере из пула такого ключа нет, то далее по пулу серверов поиск этого ключа не происходит.

А при записи ключ будет записываться на все серверы, указанные в пуле серверов.